# Python map function with multiple arguments to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, map-function

The heading may sound bizarre but here is what I mean:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return a_single_number_from_xyz
l = [(10, 'abc', 'def'), (20, 'efg', 'hij')]
print sum([ret_value_of_f_from_first_tuple, ret_value_of_f_from_second_tuple])
```

The three arguments of **function f** is the three elements of each of the tuple. 
Now, I want to apply function **f** to every tuple of list **l** and want to get the sum of those single numbers. How do I do that in a single statement? How do I map function and use list comprehension together here?

Comment: But in general, you are looking for `itertools.starmap`, so `list(itertools.starmap(f, iterable))` which is equivalent to `[f(*xs) for xs in iterable]`

Comment: Is all you need the sum of those numbers? means is using map a requirement here?

Comment: i meant that there would be some processing with those three parameters. then a single value would be returned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this *particular* case, I think you just want:

```
sum(n for n,_,_ in l)
```

But in general, you are looking for `itertools.starmap`, so

```
list(itertools.starmap(f, iterable))
```

is equivalent to

```
[f(*xs) for xs in iterable]
```

Hence the "star" map. Normally, I would just do:

```
sum(f(*xs) for xs in iterable)
```

For the general case, although:

```
sum(itertools.starmap(f, iterable))
```

Is similarly elegant to me.

Answer (score 6):

First let's make that an actual working function using all values, for example:

```
>>> def f(x, y, z):
        return x + len(y) + len(z)
```

Now your example data:

```
>>> l = [(10, 'abc', 'def'), (20, 'efg', 'hij')]
```

And one way to do it, giving map three iterables (one for each "column"):

```
>>> sum(map(f, *zip(*l)))
42
```

Lol. Didn't see that coming.

Comment: yours and @juanpa.arrivillaga 's answer are both elegant and brilliant! however, i'm accepting his answer as it was posted moments earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def f(*args):
    return sum(map(lambda x:x[0], args))

l = [(10, 'abc', 'def'), (20, 'efg', 'hij'), (30, "klm", "nop")]
print(f(*l))
```

Output:

```
60
```

Comment: i wanted to include other parameters into the calculation too...

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is just the sum, you can get it with this one-line code:

```
s = sum(t[0] for t in l)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> l = [(10, 'abc', 'def'), (20, 'efg', 'hij')]
>>> s = sum(t[0] for t in l)
>>> s
30
```