# Using a function with multiple parameters with `map`

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, typeerror

I'm trying to map a function that takes 2 arguments to a list:

```
my_func = lambda index, value: value.upper() if index % 2 else value.lower()

import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

n = map(my_func, enumerate(alphabet))
for element in n:
    print(element)
```

This gives me a `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`.

What is the correct way to map my lambda onto this input?

Comment: yep, python 3 cannot automatically unpack `lambda` arguments anymore.

Comment: I stand corrected: it doesn't work on any python version...

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Comment: This great answer was replied on a "duplicate" thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045710/1265070

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python cannot unpack lambda parameters automatically. `enumerate` returns a `tuple`, so `lambda` has to take that tuple as sole argument

You need:

```
n = map(lambda t: t[1].upper() if t[0] % 2 else t[1], enumerate(alphabet))
```

Considering now the ugliness of `map` + `lambda` + manual unpacking, I'd advise the alternate generator comprehension instead:

```
n = (value.upper() if index % 2 else value for index,value in enumerate(alphabet))
```

(I removed the `lower()` call since your input is *already* lowercase)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that bad formatting of my code, I just don't know hot ot do that. I'll do it correctly next time. Thank you Jean-François Fabre, I've already done this with comprehension, then I tried to do the same by map() to examine myself. Yor explanation is good, something new to me. Regards

Answer (score 8):

`map` will pass each value from `enumerate` as a single parameter to the callback, i.e. the `lambda` will be called with a tuple as argument. It would be pretty surprising behaviour if `map` would unpack arguments which look unpackable, since then its behaviour would depend on the values it iterates over.

To expand iterable arguments, use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead, which "applies a `*` (star)" when passing arguments:

```
from itertools import starmap

n = starmap(lambda index, value: ..., enumerate(alphabet))
```

Answer (score 4):

Python can't unpack `lambda` parameters automatically.

But you can get round this by passing an extra `range` argument to `map`:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

n = map(lambda i, v: v.upper() if i % 2 else v.lower(),
        range(len(alphabet)),
        alphabet)

for element in n:
    print(element)
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> **map**(*function*, *iterable*, ...)
>
> Return an iterator that applies function
>   to every item of iterable, yielding the results. **If additional
>   iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments
>   and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.** With
>   multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is
>   exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged
>   into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

Comment: I _never_ imagined that `map` could take more than 1 iterable!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yeh it's just one of those tricks you see once and are so surprised you cannot possibly forget.

Comment: Also, this is what I love about SO.. 3 equally acceptable answers within 10 mins!

Comment: and completely different as well!

Comment: Please split that `n = map(...)` line into multiple shorter ones. Having to scroll just to see the solution isn't great for the readability of the answer. I'd assign the lambda to a variable. Or you can just refer to the lambda as `my_func`, like the code in the question does.

Comment: Thank you all for quick responses. All of them are interesting and resolve the problem. I totally agree aith jpp, just some minutes and everything is clear:) Regards